# Tween animations when adding / removing from layout groups

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got some cards aligned in a horizontal layout group and adding and removing them works exactly how I want it to work except that I'd like to customize the animation.

For example,

[image: card layout example]

When the red card is removed, I would like to animate the blue card sliding left and the other two cards sliding right. The default animation is basically immediate. Is there any way to do this without ditching layout groups and rolling my own custom solution?

Comment: Read [this](https://answers.unity.com/answers/1158164/view.html) which explains tricky way to do that.

Comment: @Programmer. I did see that. I was just clinging onto hope there's a better way. Seems like a lot of unnecessary management.

Comment: It's either that or write your own horizontal layout group. Unity's UI is open source. Obtain the source code and create new horizontal layout group then customize it to how ever you want.